# Error 000989 Python Syntax error in Field Caclulator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.4, python-parser, error-000989

Using ArcMap 10.4 here and having some trouble running some python code in the field calculator.

I am trying to populate one text field based on the value of another text field. Here is what I am entering into the field calculator:

[image]

When I attempt to run this I get the error:

[image]

I am using 2 spaces for the 'if' line and 4 spaces for the 'return' line. Maybe I'm missing something big, brand new to coding here so any help would be great.

Comment: Give four spaces a go. If not try tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The answer is 2 parts:*

1. As @Bjorn mentioned, I needed to use an == as opposed to an =
2. I am missing an 'else' statement which is preventing the code from running; As soon as I added it, everything worked as it should. Spacing needed to be consistent but 2 vs 4 space indentation wasn't a factor.

Comment: You do not need an else there, it is implicit. Anything return ing after your if block will function as such.

Comment: I get the same error unless I include an 'else return none' at the end

Answer (score 2):

A single `=` sign is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. Change your if statement to `if luCode == 'BF':`.

4 space indentation is suggested, but not required. Consistency within an indented block however, is required.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately that didn't work. After using the == I got error 999999 @bjorn

Comment: Got it to work. It was a combination of using the == and using a 4 space indentation for the 'if' line and 6 for the 'return'. Not sure why it was required in this case. Thanks for your help! @bjorn

Comment: @Tigerwoulds If you consider my answer to be the correct one you should mark it as such so that others can benefit.